# Where/how does Firefox store hotkey settings?

Tags: firefox, hotkeys

For instance, shortcuts like ctrl+shift+w for "close window", and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the "Key Config Extension" if you want to customize the key assignments:  http://mozilla.dorando.at/readme.html 
 or "Customizable Shortcuts" at: https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/customizable-shortcuts/

You can also go to about:config and add entries for "ui.key". See Customizing Mozilla for details, at http://www-archive.mozilla.org/unix/customizing.html -- the section titled "How Key Bindings Work in Mozilla" explains about XUL & XBL.  It appears that the XUL bindings are stored in comm.jar and XBL bindings are in XML files like "bindings.xml".

Comment: Huh. Stuff like "bindings.xml"? But `find -iname "*bind*"` in my `~/.mozilla` was one of the first things I tried...

As to "Customizable Shortcuts", [it's kinda broken](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/customizable-shortcuts/reviews/508485/#review-edit-form). That's why I started looking for a way to do it manually...

Comment: Ah, you're in linux;  some files are different.  What version of FF?

Comment: Yeah, just wiped my old Vista and Windows 7 comps and installed Kubuntu a couple days ago. (So. Much. Nicer. :D ) Anyway, FF 24.0

Comment: Hm, no `*.jar" files either...

Comment: The page link to "customizing html" (in my answer) contains a great deal of detail, including which features don't work as they're supposed to. And some of the keys can be changed as prefs, as shown on that page.

Comment: Oh -- looks like it went obsolete.  There's an explanation here on how to do it with SeaMonkey, but I expect it would be very similar for FF: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201011 at the bottom, i.e. ...For native custom keybindings in for example SeaMonkey 2.12.1...

1) build from source (e.g.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Simple_SeaMonkey_build)

2) add handlers for bindings to objdir/mozilla/dist/bin/chrome/toolkit/content/global/platformHTMLBindings.xml
and/or objdir/mozilla/dist/bin/chrome/comm/content/navigator/platformNavigationBindings.xul
etc.

Comment: Uhhhhh yeah, nevermind. xD Thanks for trying to help anyway, though. ^^

Comment: Really sorry!  Hate when features go away or get broken long-term.